# ssh: port forwarding doest work for some ports

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I am connecting from windows computer to linux server with this command from cygwin:

```
ssh -v -L 2181:127.0.0.1:2181 -L 9870:217.0.0.1:9870 -L 9092:127.0.0.1:9092 -L 8088:127.0.0.1:8088 -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 ec2-user@192.168.147.4
```

Linux server has two services running on ports 8088 and 9870, both of them work in linux. I can connect to 8088 successfully:

[image]

I can connect to 9870 from console:

[image]

But strangely I can't connect to 9870 via forwarded port:

[image]

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your command.  You wrote:

```
-L 9870:217.0.0.1:9870
```

I think you meant:

```
-L 9870:127.0.0.1:9870
```

Comment: If this fixed the issue please use the Checkmark icon next to this answer to indicate that.